# Conflict markers after merge

Tags: git, merge

I recently fetched some changes to my git repository.  Myself and another developer are the only users of this repository.

Numerous files have conflict markers.

They appear to be the result of a previous merge.

```
commit 9097034d1fab59d83aca2224dd86d8faee871350
Merge: 428bbf0 dcdcae6
```

However, the other developer says he sees no conflict markers on his end.

I'm confused on how this could have happened, and even more confused on how he says he doesn't see a problem.  It would seem to me the only way would be if the developer had conflicts on the merge, but then did a force commit, thereby committing the conflicted versions of the files.

However, I didn't think git would even create the merge commit unless he fixed the conflicts first.

Any thoughts on what actions could result in conflict markers getting committed?

Answer (score 2):

If you tell Git you've resolved conflicts, it believes you - it doesn't look in the file to see whether or not there are conflict markers. So it's easy enough to commit them, if you're not thinking about what you're doing. Just `git merge`, get conflicts, ignore them, `git add ...; git commit`. **Don't do this.**

As for your situation with the various repositories, that's impossible to answer from here, but assuming that the differences aren't just uncommitted changes, the one certain thing is that you and the other developer are looking at different commits. (Are you both on your respective master branches?) What you probably want to do is just look at everything all at the same time. If you can directly add the other developer's repository as a remote, do that. Otherwise, ask him to create a temporary branch representing his current branch, and push that to the central repository. Run `git fetch --all` to make sure you've fetched everything, and then use `gitk --all` or `gitk master origin/master origin/his-temp-branch` (or `gitk master origin/master his-repo/master` if you've added his as a remote) to view the history of all the branches. You'll find some sort of discrepancy.